# Got error FRMT.NOT ENT BGNG WITH in Sabre webservices

Tags: .net, sabre, sabredav

I have tried with this error. I got when i called Api: TravelItineraryAddInfo

Request data to sabre:
[data send to sabre webserivces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTuo1.png)

Sabre reponsed data:

```
    <Message>.FRMT.NOT ENT BGNG WITH</Message>
    <ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</ShortText>
```

pls help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

As per format finder document [tkter949](https://formatfinder.sabre.com/Content/Ticketing/TicketingErrors/FRMTNOTENTBGNGWITH.aspx?ItemID=0c2cb74cd2724a089ea438e90bb46eb1), you have invalid characters in any of these:

- Form of Payment
- Name Field
- Phone Field

I can see in your example that your not ticketing yet, so my guess is that the address field does not support commas. Try a shorter, more concise address in the `AgencyInfo` element.